# Dynamic References to Changing DLL Locations after a TFS 2013 Build

Tags: c#, dll, build, build-process

I'm fairly new at C#, but I am trying to create some automation using Selenium and I'm running into a problem when referencing other DLL's.  I created a framework project that handles the identifying and interaction of all elements on the web pages.  This framework DLL is referenced in my test project.  I built everything locally and then decided to upload it to TFS and that’s when I started to have problems.  If I modify the framework project and create a new build, my test project still references the old DLL and doesn’t reflect the changes.  When I create a new build in TFS, it creates a new folder with the latest build name/number and that’s what I don’t know how to reference.  How do I reference an ever-changing folder name to make sure that my test project will always point to the latest DLL?
I'm using TFS 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install the DLL on the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) of the machine? If the physical lookup of the application fails, the reference points to the GAC.

Please look at this [link](http://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/how-to-install-a-dll-to-the-gac-on-windows-2012-using-only-powershell-without-having-to-install-sdk-or-visual-studio/).

Comment: Thanks, DustineTheGreat.  I will give that a try, but I was hoping for something that would automatically place new DLL's in a referenced location when I run a new build on my framework project.  I'd rather not manually place new DLL's for them to be found by my test project.  Can that be done here?  Is placing DLL's on the GAC a best practice?

Comment: I'd rather not answer if placing the assemblies (DLLs) on the GAC a best practice. But as for your problem, this might solve the issue. Besides, it's very easy to install and uninstall the DLLs on the GAC. In the link I posted, it uses Powershell scripts. But you can also use the gacutil which is included in the installation of .NET SDK (or installation of Visual Studio).